# How to count the number of digits of an integer in python3 with recursion.Cannot convert int to str and cannot use loops

Tags: python-3.x

## Needs to return the number of digits in an integer using recursion.NO LOOPS and cannot use str function either.I have the general case but i need help with the base case:

```
    def count(x):
       x=abs(x)
      #general case
      if x<10:
       return 1
      #base case 

    x=123
    print(count(x))
```

Comment: Are you passing an int to the function or a string. cause currently your passing a string so can just return `len(x)`

Comment: sorry about that,that was a mistake i just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right track, so when its less than 10 you know that its a single digit so you can return 1, otherwise its greater than 10 so return 1 + the result of the function passing in x // 10

```py
def count(x):
    if abs(x) > 10:
        return 1 + count(x // 10)
    return 1


for i in (1, 23, 345, 454564, 34, -345, -98):
    print(f'There are {count(i)} digits in the number {i}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
There are 1 digits in the number 1
There are 2 digits in the number 23
There are 3 digits in the number 345
There are 6 digits in the number 454564
There are 2 digits in the number 34
There are 3 digits in the number -345
There are 2 digits in the number -98
```